# Simple Excel Applescript

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I am new to Applescripts and Excel 08?  I want to write one that colors arbitrarily preselected cells in Excel 08 specific colors. I can get it to  write want in an preselected cell and even bold the font...but for some reason it will not change the color of the cell...

```
print("Tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
set formula of active cell to "excellent answer"
set bold of font object of active cell to true
activate cell active cell");
```

This part doesn't work for some reason`

```
print("tell interior object of active cell of active sheet
    set color index to 3
    set pattern to pattern gray 50
    set pattern color index to 13
end tell");
```

not sure why

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set the color of a particular cell in Excel 08 (and 2011 now) using the following AppleScript:

```
tell sheet "Sheet1" of theWorkbook    
set color of interior object of range C2:C2 to {255, 255, 0}
end tell
```

I had to specify the color on a particular range and use the Red, Blue, and Green component values (from 0-255).